# Selenium webdriver, how to access network tab in inspect element and save data from there

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Please refer to the attached screenshot, I need to save data from 'Save all as HAR' option automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that selenium provides a way to interact with the inspector. You might have to do something like inject Javascript into the page that re-submits the request and then saves the response/request data on the page in a hidden element. You could then simply get the text from that hidden element via selenium.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the help! it would be great if you can elaborate a bit more on how to inject javascript and get the text from hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

No, Selenium is not the tool you want to use to do this.  [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) may be useful, or [this site](http://www.seleniumtests.com/2012/10/capture-network-traffic-using-webdriver.html) suggests using a proxy server to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not give you the ability to track network traffic.  It does however allow you to configure a proxy that the browser will use when it is started up.

S to get around your problem you will need to use something like the BrowserMobProxy:

```
BrowserMobProxy browserMobProxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
browserMobProxy.start();
Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserMobProxy, InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress());
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

You can then perform some actions with Selenium and when you want to collect a Har file perform:

```
browserMobProxy.getHar();
```

For more information about the BrowserMobProxy have a look at the [BrowserMobProxy Homepage](https://bmp.lightbody.net)